# Logic for getting number of pages

Tags: c#, .net-1.1

If a page can have 27 items printed on it and number of items can be any positive number then how can I find number of pages if I have number of items, I tried Modulus and division but didn't helped.

```
double TotalNumberOfPages = NumberOfItems/27;
int a = (int)TotalNumberOfPages;
```

above code works but not logically as if double is 3.00000000000001 I want it to round up as 4 not 3, for some reason I can't use "round" method.

Comment: You want to round 3.00000000000001 up to 4? It's hard to get much closer to 3 than 3.00000000000001...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Surely your `TotalNumberOfPages` should be an integer.  In that case, try:

```
int PageSize = 27;
int TotalNumberOfPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)NumberOfItems / (double)PageSize);
```

Comment: The most important part of your answer is the call to `Math.Ceiling`, not the type conversion.

Answer (score 2):

```
(NumberOfItems + ItemsPerPage - 1) / ItemsPerPage;
```

In your case ItemsPerPage = 27

Comment: if NumberOfItems is double use (int)NumberOfItems. I'm not sure why downvote :)